# Bot Service Node.js deployment from a non-root directory

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions

I have bot service and following structure:

```
git-root
¦
+--- mybot(bot service app)
¦    ¦
¦    +--- messages (all js code; ex. index.js) 
¦    +--- PostDeployScripts (default script created from template, no changes)
¦
+--- other app
```

Taken the recommendation from [another post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee65307f-bb41-4219-bf5a-9522ca9fa38c/overwrite-function-with-a-git-push?forum=AzureFunctions). I do: Azure -> My Bot -> Settings -> App Settings -> (PROJECT = mybot) -> Save -> Continuous Integration -> Sync.

Result: The bot is not deployed from the mybot directory.

Few notes:

- I would prefer to avoid any configuration files in the git-root
- All suggestions in the web Ive found have a link to .csproj file, which I don't have. I'm using default Bot Service template and Intellij IDEA for coding.

Comment: What is your deployment source? GitHub?

Comment: Yes. It is GitHub

Comment: For more information on Bot Service CI, check out this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-continuous-integration

Comment: See also: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a custom deployment script that tells azure how to deploy your app. That deployment script goes in your gitroot. If you don't want to commit the `.deployment` file in the root of your git repo, you can configure it through app settings instead. You'd have to configure an app setting for the `command` to point to your custom deployment script. See this wiki for more info https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments

Comment: ahmelsayed, the page says I can configure the .deployment file with "[config] project = mybot", next it says "you can use App Settings to set the same values that are supported in the .deployment file", that means my configuration is already valid based on the provided spec. Lets assume spec is wrong and I need 'deploy.sh', can you provide an example that I can use to deploy my Node app to Bot Service?

Comment: note that the project setting is for VS projects not just any project. Though to create a custom deployment script check this page https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script